# Organization tag -> merge into file-management?

Tags: discussion, tags

While we're on a New Year's tag cleanup kick.... [organization](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organization) and [file-management](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-management) both have 35 or so questions, and all of the organization questions do really seem to be about organizing digital files.

Should these be merged?

Comment: I can't see a real distinction either, to be honest.

Comment: JoanneC: can you do the merge? I can clean up after....

Comment: Merge is done, file-management is the master.

Comment: JoanneC: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this one was next on my hit list of tags and I was going to propose exactly the same thing. Let's do it.